# Facebook SDK Error in Android Studio

Tags: gradle, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

Using Android Studio `v0.8.14` with Facebook SDK `v3.22.0`.

In Android Studio, adding `facebook-sdk/facebook` folder as a module. And module has been added as a dependcy in `Project Structure` setting. Gradle sync is fine. Although when I try to run app getting those weird errors:

```
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/AuthorizationClient.java
Error:(29, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/FacebookRequestError.java
Error:(19, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/WebDialog.java
Error:(40, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/LoginActivity.java
Error:(24, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/Settings.java
Error:(33, 28) error: cannot find symbol class BuildConfig
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/internal/ImageDownloader.java
Error:(25, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/FriendPickerFragment.java
Error:(29, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/GraphObjectAdapter.java
Error:(27, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/LikeView.java
Error:(35, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/widget/PlacePickerFragment.java
Error:(36, 28) error: cannot find symbol class R
/Users/myuser/application-path/facebook/src/com/facebook/RequestBatch.java
```

Here is facebook build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

project.group = 'com.facebook.android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

def isSnapshot = version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')
def ossrhUsername = hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
def ossrhPassword = hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""

task setVersion {
    // The version will be derived from source
    project.version = null
    def sdkVersionFile = file('src/com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.java')
    sdkVersionFile.eachLine{
        def matcher = (it =~ /(?:.*BUILD = \")(.*)(?:\".*)/)
        if (matcher.matches()) {
          project.version = matcher[0][1]
          return
        }
    }
    if (project.version.is('unspecified')) {
      throw new GradleScriptException('Version could not be found.', null)
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
            authentication(userName: ossrhUsername, password: ossrhPassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name 'Facebook-Android-SDK'
            artifactId = 'facebook-android-sdk'
            packaging 'aar'
            description 'Facebook Android SDK'
            url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'

            scm {
                connection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                developerConnection 'scm:git@github.com:facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git'
                url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk'
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/LICENSE.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id 'facebook'
                    name 'Facebook'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.dependsOn(setVersion)

signing {
    required { !isSnapshot && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}

task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += project.android.libraryVariants.toList().first().javaCompile.classpath
}
```

This is also build.gradle for app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

def AAVersion = '3.2'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.general.application"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'com.general.application'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

I've already checked all docs even YouTube tutorials that use old version of Android Studio (e.g v0.5.x). Facebook docs are deprecated and samples are not suitable with Android Studio, so I couldn't find right configuration.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should use Android Studio v1.0+ for the most recent versions of the SDK. The gradle plugin inside Android Studios was updated, and the build files in the SDK has been updated accordingly. It might not work with older versions of AS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found the answer myself.

My `Android Studio` is out of date so updated as suggested. Than cleared all the `Facebook SDK` stuff including gradle files and re-added. That's all.